# Forcing Subclasses to Be Immutable

Tags: javascript, oop, typescript, design-patterns, immutable.js

I have a base class with some properties:

```
class Component {
    readonly id: number
    readonly type: number
}
```

And I'd like to have some subclasses:

```
class HealthComponent extends Component {
    max_health: number,
    current_health: number
}

etc.
```

What I want is essentially for `HealthComponent` to have the same behavior as an `Immutable.Record`:

```
const health = HealthComponent(100, 100);
health.max_health = 40; // Shouldn't work
const new_health = new HealthComponent(40, health.current_health); // Works
```

All of the classes are just data; no behavior (if there is any behavior, it will be in static methods, not instance methods). Now I want to enforce as much as possible that the subclasses are immutable (in the sense that modifications are allowed, but making changes results in a new object or throws an error a la Immutable.js) and I can't figure out the best way to do this.

Tthe best thing I've come up with is to just have each subclass have a readonly `data` member that is an `Immutable.Record` with the appropriate fields, but even this isn't quite right because changing it would return a new `data` object, but I really want a whole new `Component` object, and this also doesn't really enforce that all components follow this convention.

The other thing I've considered is to have the base class be an `Immutable.Record` with a `data: Immutable.Map` field and then the subclasses provide an `Immutable.Map` to the `super` constructor with all the keys, but then people could just add new keys willy nilly which isn't ideal either.

Is there a magic design pattern that could help me here?

Comment: That is a fairly impenetrable paragraph. It's best usually to limit paragraphs to 2-3 sentences and then a new paragraph (within reason).

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Readonly` [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html).

```
class Component {
    constructor(public id: number, public type: number) {

    }
}

class HealthComponent extends Component {
    constructor(public id: number, public type: number, public max_health: number, public current_health: number) {
        super(id, type);
     }
}

let hc: Readonly<HealthComponent> = new HealthComponent(1, 2, 3, 4);
hc.max_health = 40; // Error
```

Consider using an `interface` if you don't have behavior.

```
interface Component {
    id: number
    type: number
}

interface HealthComponent extends Component {
    max_health: number;
    current_health: number;
}

let hc: Readonly<HealthComponent> = {
    id: 1,
    type: 2,
    max_health: 3,
    current_health: 4
};

hc.max_health = 40; // Error
```